# I want to merge multiple line_comments into a single comment using xquery

Tags: xml, comments, xquery, string-concatenation

I am new to xml and xquery.I am having an xml document which has multiple TEXT_LINE for same line item. I want to merge these multiple TEXT_LINE data into a single comment based on PO_ITEM.
Here, PO_ITEM 00020 has two TEXT_LINE tags which I need to merge into a single one. Same for PO_ITEM 00030.

```
<XI_PO_TEXTS>
 <PO_ITEM>00020</PO_ITEM>
 <TEXT_LINE>this is comment one</TEXT_LINE>
</XI_PO_TEXTS>
<XI_PO_TEXTS>
 <PO_ITEM>00020</PO_ITEM>
<TEXT_LINE>tis is comment two</TEXT_LINE>
</XI_PO_TEXTS>
<XI_PO_TEXTS>
 <PO_ITEM>00030</PO_ITEM>
 <TEXT_LINE>this is comment three </TEXT_LINE>
</XI_PO_TEXTS>
<XI_PO_TEXTS>
 <PO_ITEM>00030</PO_ITEM>>
 <TEXT_LINE>this is comment four</TEXT_LINE>
</XI_PO_TEXTS>
```

I have tried using string-join but it is combining all 4 lines for each PO_ITEM.

```
`string-join($Source/XI_PO_TEXTS[fn:data($Source/XI_PO_TEXTS/PO_ITEM)=fn:data($comment/PO_ITEM)]/TEXT_LINE,'')`
```

Please suggest how the query should be to merge line comments belongs to specific PO_ITEM?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your goal is, it may help to add the intended output to your answer, i.e. the transformed xml.

Comment: In XQuery 3.0 or 3.1 this is a standard text book grouping example so check your favourite XQuery introduction on grouping using `for $text in //XI_PO_TEXTS group by $item := $text/PO_ITEM return <XI_PO_TEXTS>{head($text)/PO_ITEM, <TEXT_LINE>{data($text/TEXT_LINE)}</TEXT_LINE>}</XI_PO_TEXTS>`.

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 3.0 or 3.1 this is a standard text book grouping example using `group by`:

```
for $text in //XI_PO_TEXTS 
group by $item := $text/PO_ITEM 
return 
    <XI_PO_TEXTS>
    {
        head($text)/PO_ITEM, 
        <TEXT_LINE>
        {
            data($text/TEXT_LINE)
        }
        </TEXT_LINE>
    }
    </XI_PO_TEXTS>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPs5/1